# Spacing ImageButtons in Android

Tags: android, layout, imagebutton, android-relativelayout

How do you space ImageButtons?

With RelativeLayout, I can have them side by side but I want a gap between them.
How do I place the buttons in the center and at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With RelativeLayout, I can have them
>   side by side but I want a gap between
>   them.

Use `android:layout_marginTop` and related properties.

> How do I place the buttons in the
>   center and at the bottom of the
>   screen?

`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`